# Manage table with a lot of data twig

Tags: symfony, html-table, twig

I'm trying to create a table, but as there is a lot of for, I'm getting lost every time.

This is the closest thing I've got at the moment:

[image: Tables at the moment]

Lines should be *Bacterie name* (nom), Column *Mole name* (nom) and then a result between them.

On my screen, this is not bad, but I know my synthax won't work because if I add more result, they will not be implemented in the table.

I want the table to be like this :

[image: Result I want]

And when I add results with *bactérie* and *Molecule*, table should update in consequence :

```
 <table class = "table">
  <caption>{{ session.antibiotique.nom }}</caption>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  {% for i in 0..((session.antibiotique.resultats|length)|price) -1 %}
      <th scope="col">{{ session.antibiotique.resultats[i].molecule.nom}} </th>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ session.antibiotique.resultats[0].bacterie.nom}}</th>
  {% for i in 0..((session.antibiotique.resultats|length)|price) -1 %}
    <td> {{ session.antibiotique.resultats[i].result}} </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

*the `price` filter on twig return the sqrt value*

Comment: Not positive exactly what is being asked but transforming an array inside of twig can be challenging to say the least.  I'd suggest writing a php based transformer which accepts as input your original data set and returns a view array which matches your desired output format.  At that point the twig stuff becomes trivial.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a session to store your array? And then is there a reason you are then looping through the array with a counter like that? Seems like a lot of work to get around things that are so nicely built into twig.